# Test Complete - Andriod automation in real device - Name Mapping holds duplicates objects(Device, Device 2, Windows, Windows2)

Tags: android, testcomplete

Objects are duplicated in the Name Mapping repository. Test Complete is not able to recognize the object. This Happens only in my PC when i perform the same execution from my colleagues machines(multiple pcs) it is working fine and there is no duplicate objects , no script change required

This Problem is only with my PC(personal computer)

For Reference Duplicate Objects are like below,

device
device2
explorer
explorer2
gui
gui2

Additional note: Just connected only one real device and i dont have any emulators installed

Will be really great if you can show the direction or share your thoughts

Kind Regards & Thanks

Answer (score 0):

This is a common thing in TC if properties of objects are changing.
Please take a look at the name mapping and see what properties are being looked for in order to find the right item.

Comment: There is NO change in properties of objects(same codebase and apk file installed in my colleagues machine and we did execution it was succeful. test passed, we dint change a bit of the code or modified any properties of the object in NameMapping) Problem affected only in my machine! What would be the reason ? it can able to run succesfully in multiples machine why it dint run in my pc and all the major parent objects are duplicated. i.e, device, device2. Appreciate your response !!

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest a re-install.  If that doesn't fix it, you should reach out to support.

Comment: I've tried a re-install of the testcomplete tool still facing the same issue. Thanks for your suggestions and recommendations. it will great if you could share the TestComplete support email id or contact number ?

Answer (score 0):

Opening a support case would help us resolve this issue, as we could get down to the actual cause of this remapping of objects.